# how to invoke a play application without hitting the URL (http request)?

Tags: playframework-2.1

I'm using play application (using Play version 2.1.0) with RabbitMQ and do not have any view component.
So i would like to invoke this play application without hitting the execution URL `(http://localhost:9000/<routing_info>)` on server startup.

Would also like to know if there is any way in Play 2.1.0 version to run the application on server startup, i mean bootstrapping. Is this option available in play 2.1.0.
As i've read through the documentation its mentioned only for 1.2 version.

Please help!!

Comment: It could be used in thread!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play allows you to define a 'global' object which will be instantiated automatically by Play when the application starts.

In `application.conf` you should find the following:

```
# Global object class
# ~~~~~
# Define the Global object class for this application.
# Default to Global in the root package.
application.global=global.Global
```

On a new play application, this line is commented out.  I've uncommented it and made it point to an object called `Global` in the `global` package.  You can make it what ever you want.

Your global object should extend `GlobalSettings`.

In my applications, I use a static initialiser block to run code when that class is loaded:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings
{
  static
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, will try this out.!!